# how does knowing the indeterminate form of a limit help in solving that limit?

Tags: limits

i know what indeterminate forms are, but fail to find their use while solving questions on limits. I know that 0/0 and infinity/infinity forms indicate use of l'Hopital's rule, but i dont know what other indeterminate forms lead us to, for example, how do you proceed when you get suppose indeterminate form 0* infinity or infinity-infinity?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the identities

$$f\cdot g=\frac f{\dfrac 1g}$$ and $$f-g=f\cdot\left(1-\frac gf\right),$$ which reduce the problems to known forms.

---

Assuming that the conditions for L'Hospital hold,

$$f\cdot g=\frac f{\dfrac 1g}\to\frac{f'}{-\dfrac{g'}{g^2}}=-\frac{f'g^2}{g'}$$

and

$$f-g=\dfrac{1-\dfrac gf}{\dfrac1f}\to\frac{-\dfrac{g'f-gf'}{f^2}}{-\dfrac{f'}{f^2}}=\frac{g'f-gf'}{f'}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can change your limit a little bit to fit to L'Hopistal's rule. So for example, $\frac{1}{x}ln(x)$ is what you call $0\cdot\infty$ so you can write this as $\frac{lnx}{x}$ which now you can use L'Hopistal's rule as it is in the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: Not a very helpful example, the OP can certainly do that. Better show $x\log x$ for $x\to0$.